# Dovecot sieve not processing messages

Tags: dovecot, sieve

After recently getting [amavis to correctly tag messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/63384/amavis-sa-not-marking-messages-as-spam), they're coming through with appropriate `X-Spam-Flag: YES` headers.  I've set up dovecot with the sieve protocol:

```
protocol managesieve {
  # Login executable location.
  login_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve-login

  # MANAGESIEVE executable location. See IMAP's mail_executable above for 
  # examples how this could be changed.
  mail_executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/managesieve

  # Maximum MANAGESIEVE command line length in bytes. This setting is 
  # directly borrowed from IMAP. But, since long command lines are very
  # unlikely with MANAGESIEVE, changing this will not be very useful.  
  #managesieve_max_line_length = 65536

  # Specifies the location of the symlink pointing to the active script in
  # the sieve storage directory. This must match the SIEVE setting used by
  # deliver (refer to http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Sieve#location for more
  # info). Variable substitution with % is recognized.
  sieve=/var/mail/%d/%n/.dovecot.sieve

  # This specifies the path to the directory where the uploaded scripts must
  # be stored. In terms of '%' variable substitution it is identical to
  # dovecot's mail_location setting used by the mail protocol daemons.
  sieve_storage=/var/mail/%d/%n/sieve

  # If, for some inobvious reason, the sieve_storage remains unset, the 
  # managesieve daemon uses the specification of the mail_location to find out 
  # where to store the sieve files (see explaination in README.managesieve). 
  # The example below, when uncommented, overrides any global mail_location 
  # specification and stores all the scripts in '~/mail/sieve' if sieve_storage 
  # is unset. However, you should always use the sieve_storage setting.
  # mail_location = mbox:~/mail

  # To fool managesieve clients that are focused on timesieved you can
  # specify the IMPLEMENTATION capability that the dovecot reports to clients 
  # (default: dovecot).
  #managesieve_implementation_string = Cyrus timsieved v2.2.13
}
```

I can see that managesieve-login is running.  managesieve is not.  The file does exist.  Any ideas on where to start?  Enabling `mail_debug = yes` doesn't seem to tell me anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get dovecot sieve into use, you must use the dovecot LDA called deliver. Sieve is handled by a plugin of it.

See http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA

Answer (score 0):

The managesieve is a frontend to managing the sieve configuration for a user.

The dovecot package is only a IMAP/POP3 mailserver - it will not (and should not) actually do the sieve processing.

The processing should be handled by your MDA program (Cyrus, for example). You need to configure that piece that's actually delivering mail on your system and tell it to parse sieve scripts.